# What is wrong with this yacc file?

Tags: c, syntax-error, yacc

I'm getting this error **tema4.y:13.19-26: syntax error, unexpected typetype** on the following code, please help me!

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
%}
%union {
int intval;
char* strval;
char* charval;
}
%token <charval>SHR <intval>NR
%token CMP
%type <strval>str <intval>expr
%nonassoc CMP '|'   
%left '+' '-'
%left '*' '`' '#'

%start s
%%
s:str {printf("%s \n",$<strval>$);}
 | expr {printf("%s \n",$<intval>$)}
 ;
str : str '+' str {
                   char* s=malloc(strlen($1)+strlen($3)+1);
                   strcpy(s,$1);
                   strcat(s,$3);
                   $$=s;
                   }
    | str '-' str {
                   char *s=malloc(strlen($1));
                   char *sir=malloc(strlen($1)-strlen($3));
                   char *pt,*ps;
                   int i;
                   strcpy(s,$1);
                   pt=strstr(s,$3);   
                   if(pt) {
                           ps=pt+strlen($3);
                           strncpy(pt,ps,strlen(ps)); 
                           ps+=strlen(ps);
                           strncpy(sir,s,strlen($1)-strlen($3));
                          }
                  $$=sir;
                  }
    | str '*' NR {
                   int i;
                   char* s=malloc(strlen($1)*NR+1);
                   for(i=0;i<$3;i++)
                   {
                      strcat(s,$1);
                   }
                   $$=s;
                 }
    | str '#' NR {
                   char *s=malloc($3+1);
                   strcpy(s,$1);
                   if($3>strlen($1)) {printf("Nr prea mare\n");exit(1);}
                   else {s=s+strlen(s)-$3;
                        $$=s;}
                 }
    | NR '`' str {
                  char *s=malloc($1+1); 
                  strncpy(s,$3,$1);
                  $$=s;
                 }

    | '(' str ')' {
                  $$=$2;
                  }
    | SHR {
         char* s=malloc(strlen($1));
         strcpy(s,$1);
         $$=s;
         }
    | expr
    ;
expr : str CMP str {
                  if(strcmp($1,$3)) $$=0;
                  else $$=1;
                  }
    | '|' str '|' {
                  $$=strlen($2);
                  }
 ;
%%
int main(){
   yyparse();
}
```

Comment: That line is `%type str expr`. Obviously there's something wrong with it. How about dicing into yacc's documentation and finding out how `%type` is ought to be used?

Comment: I'm using gcc, I couldn`t write '<' brace here, but when I compile, all the braces are where they're supposed to be, the error is to the start symbol and I don`t understand why.

Comment: To include code paste it, select it, and press Ctrl-K to indent each line four spaces. This works like `<pre><code>` but preserves `<` and `>` angle brackets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

John has the answer for your first error -- only one type in a `%type` or `%token` declaration.  For the second error (type clash), the problem is your rule `str: expr ;` -- str is a `<strval>` while expr is an `<intval>`, so the default action (`{ $$ = $1; }` effectively) has a type clash.

You also have a reduce/reduce conflict somewhere -- you'll need to run yacc with -d and look at the resulting y.output file for more detail on what the conflict is.

Answer (score 2):

As best I can tell you can only have one `<type>` in a `%token` or `%type` declaration. You can have multiple tokens or non-terminals but only one type name. Try splitting those lines:

```
%token <charval> SHR
%token <intval> NR
%token CMP
%type <strval> str
%type <intval> expr
```

Comment: I already tried that, but when I did the following error showed: **tema4_y.y:78.7-10: warning: type clash on default action: <strval> != <intval>
conflicts: 1 reduce/reduce